# Absolute-positioning on ipad?

Tags: ipad, css-position

Ive used absolute positioning on this page to keep the footer at the bottom of the window;
http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/ppr6/contact

This works fine in browsers but with an i pad (in landscape) when you scroll down the footer moves up. How can I keep it fixed so it behaves like a normal browser?

Thanks

Comment: Ive had a look at the following solution but it disables my iphones ability to zoom in and out. As the demo also does this I dont think I can use this solution.
http://cubiq.org/iscroll

Comment: Could I do this with CSS media queries? Ive found tutorials on how to select the ipad as opposed to the iphone, but I cant figure out how to differentiate between an ipad and a computer screen with a similar resolution.

Comment: Can anyone at least confirm if this is possible or not? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, but not with `position: absolute`

Check this solution for [sticky footers](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) using more flexible css.

It works perfectly in **mobile safari**.

Comment: Thats not what i was asking. I need the footer to stay on the viewable area of the screen, not go below it when there is more content than fits in the viewable area. Thanks